# Redux saga enters in infinite loop state of calling api endpoint

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, redux-saga

I am using Redux for state management and saga as a middleware. For some reason my app is in some infinite loop state of calling API endpoint.

This is my actions:

```
export const GET_USERS = "GET_USERS";
export const getUsers = () => ({
  type: GET_USERS,
});

export const GET_USERS_SUCCESS = `${GET_USERS}_SUCCESS`;
export const getUsersSuccess = (data) => ({
  type: GET_USERS_SUCCESS,
  payload: data,
});

export const GET_USERS_FAIL = `${GET_USERS}_FAIL`;
export const getUsersFail = (error) => ({
  type: GET_USERS_FAIL,
  payload: error,
});
```

This is saga:

```
export function* getUsers$() {
  try {
    const users = yield getUsersAPI();
    yield put(actions.getUsersSuccess(users.data));
  } catch (error) {
    yield put(actions.getUsersFail(error));
  }
}

export default function* () {
  yield all([takeLatest(actions.getUsers, getUsers$)]);
}
```

This is a reducer:

```
export default (state = initialState(), action) => {

  const { type, payload } = action;

  switch (type) {
    case actions.GET_USERS:
      return {
        ...state,
        users: {
          ...state.users,
          inProgress: true,
        },
      };
    case actions.GET_USERS_SUCCESS:
      return {
        ...state,
        users: {
          inProgress: false,
          data: payload,
        },
      };
    case actions.GET_USERS_FAIL:
      return {
        ...state,
        users: {
          ...state.users,
          inProgress: false,
          error: payload,
        },
      };
    default:
      return state;
  }
};
```

And this is a component connected with redux:

```
const Home = (props) => {

    useEffect(() => {
        props.getUsers();
        console.log('props', props.data);
    }, []);
   return(
    <h1>Title</h1>
   );
}

const mapStateToProps = ({
    users: {
        users: {
            data
        }
    }
}) => ({data})


export default connect(mapStateToProps, {getUsers})(Home);
```

Why is this happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is due to the fact that you misused the `sagas` in your example. As with any other `effect creator` as the first parameter must pass a `pattern`, which can be read in more detail in the documentation. The first parameter can also be passed a `function`, but in a slightly different way. View [documentation](https://redux-saga.js.org/docs/api/) (block `take(pattern)`).

In your case, you are passing a function there that will return an object

```js
{
  type: 'SOME_TYPE',
  payload: 'some_payload',
}
```

Because of this, your `worker` will react to **ALL** events that you `dispatch`.
As a result, you receive data from the server, `dispatch` a new `action` to save data from the store. And besides the `reducer`, your `getUsers` saga will be called for this action too. And so on ad infinitum.

**Solution**

To solve this problem, just use the string constant `actions.GET_USERS` that you defined in your actions.
And your `sagas` will look like this:

```js
export function* getUsers$() {
  try {
    const users = yield getUsersAPI();
    yield put(actions.getUsersSuccess(users.data));
  } catch (error) {
    yield put(actions.getUsersFail(error));
  }
}

export default function* () {
  yield all([takeLatest(actions.GET_USERS, getUsers$)]);
}
```

This should fix your problem.